# Use unknown key in the v-model in vue js for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects, v-for

I have a dynamically made object of facets.
An example of the data could be:

```
facets: {
    type: ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'],
    color: ['color1', 'color2']
}
```

I also have an empty object for filters.
I then loop over the facets object and make checkbox groups for each facet. I want the `v-model` to be `filters."name of the facet"`, so: `filters.type` and `filters.color`. I do not know the names forehand. I tried using the key in a loop but that does not work.

My loop looks like this:

```
<li v-for="(facet, facetKey, facetIndex) in facets" class="filter-item">
    <strong>{{ facetKey }}</strong>
    <div v-for="(value, valueIndex) in facet" class="form__fieldset" :key="valueIndex">
        <div class="form__field-wrap">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="filters[facetKey]" :id="value.toLowerCase().trim()" :value="value">
            <label :for="value.toLowerCase().trim()">{{ value }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

If I hardcode v-model to `filters.type`, It works as intended. Has anyone achieved this type of dynamic v-models?

Comment: show us your ````filters```` variable

Comment: @VojinPurić as described in the question, my `filters` is an empty object. I want to build the object on the fly from what's inside the facets object.

Answer (score 0):

Populate `filters` with your facets properties

```
filters = ref({
  ...facets.value
})
```

Here is the playground [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9U9tu2zAM/RXCL04AW0a7NyMtMOxp2P6gCgrHphu1siRIsrPA8L+Pki/N2qF+MUUeHh6K1Jh8N4YNPSZlcnC1FcaDQ9+bR65EZ7T1MILFFmCC1uoOUsKmXHFVa+U8tFWN3sEDBNBu5Aro81eDJTyl4X+XZhCN+9X4lh6zGVdrqW0ARiMio3WfHrma9lsNIT3aUGSrwRibK7Ohkj3O6EMxN0DS6eCxM7LySCeAQyOGaJApBQx5q+0DT3aRJJu7+IXXxfqpGvyzB6GW9ngCtayco4xZSy6InScro/NWq5fHcdyIYJpIzexeQKTgvW5UnUH8fah2W0zb7vm5FSgbmgkFyje8kv89bdOwlfhPbn6xlfkHGdFCmd7HWRG8PmP9dtJESCI73aDcmnVPa1fHIEE0qwLm9W99QfujcrjbM29Ft9sHSIyuqM+FZXVCCeV8FV8xhRuN8XidMe223eJmqItNKLG44tjPd3EqywIFFvLEyJaw7UmSJfPG511l2KvTit5E3Da+BGgRSlh2nJSH3koyzt4bVxaFa+vwkl4d0/alIIvZXnnRIUPX5SerLw4tEfNk2f/IUZBzoJWySAO1aL/i/AD9xBtoJ3oMyfQXzr1Gaw==) to a working example

Comment: I see, but how would you use it with v-model/data?